# How does an extension cord on a radio apparently function as a reception antenna if placed in certain positions?

Tags: waves, acoustics, radio

I have an old radio and the antenna broke off at some point years ago. The radio has somewhat poor reception, as the room it's in faces a courtyard or alleyway. I have to position the radio just right to hear a station properly, which doesn't always work. Today I noticed (after many years) that hanging the extension cord high on a hook gives pretty good reception. How does the extension cord function as an antenna?

Comment: Random wires pick up signals, and can carry them into the interior of the radio proper. Some of the signal may well leak through the power supply filtering, or just be re-radiated within the radio enclosure, with sufficient power to get detected and amplified. Recall that a crystal radio requires no power by itself. Are you getting AM or FM radio?

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications. I get both AM and FM, but usually listen only to FM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you take special precautions to isolate the antenna input, every conductor attached to the radio is part of the antenna. The common "whip" antenna is really only half of an antenna. The radio works by sensing the potential difference between two circuit "nodes", but the whip antenna connection is only one node. However, any radio contains conductors and may be connected to external conductors like a power cord, so there's always something that functions as the other half.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations.